# How to use Parametric differentiation method to evaluate this integral $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\ln \left( 1+x^2 \right)}{\left( 1+x^2 \right) ^2}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I know use the triangular tape transformation  is a method .

**I am trying finding another method**

$$
\begin{align*}
&\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{\ln \left( 1+x^2 \right)}{\left( 1+x^2 \right) ^2}dx}
&\\
&\xrightarrow{x=\tan t}\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{\displaystyle\frac{\ln \left( \sec ^2t \right)}{\sec ^2t}dt}\,\,
&\\
&=-\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{2\cos ^2t\ln \left( \cos t \right) dt}\,\,    
&\\
&=-\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{2\cos ^2t\ln \left( \cos t \right) dt}\,\,    
&\\
&=-\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{\ln \left( \cos t \right) d\left( t+\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t \right)}
&\\
&=-\left( t+\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t \right) \ln \left( \cos t \right) \mid_{0}^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}+\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left( t+\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t \right) d\ln\cos t}
&\\
&=\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{td\ln\cos t}+\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\sin 2td\ln\cos t}
&\\
&=t\ln\cos t\mid_{0}^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}-\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{\ln\cos tdt}-\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x\displaystyle\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}d}t
&\\
&=-\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{\ln\cos tdt}-\displaystyle\int_0^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin ^2td}t
&\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\pi \ln 2}{2}-\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}
&\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{2\pi \ln 2-\pi}{4}
&
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Do you want be checked of you want find simpler method?

Comment: @Adam Wrzesiński、yeah I am try to use the follow method, $I\left( a \right) =\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\ln \left( a+x^2 \right)}{\left( 1+x^2 \right) ^2}dx}$

Answer (score 3):

For another approach to your problem, you can define the function
$$ I(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(a^2+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx\,. \tag{1}$$
Your integral is then given by $I(1)$.

Note that
$$ I'(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{2a}{(a^2+x^2)(1+x^2)^2}dx= \frac12  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2a}{(a^2+x^2)(1+x^2)^2}dx\,. $$
This integral can be evaluated using the residue theorem (the poles are at $x=\pm i, \pm ia$). We obtain the result
$$ I'(a) = \frac{\pi (2+a)}{2(1+a)^2}\,,$$
as you have obtained with your method.
Integrating this expression with respect to $a$, we obtain
$$ I(a) = \frac{\pi}{2(a+1)} \biggl(a+(a+1) \ln(a+1)\biggr) +c 
\sim \frac{\pi}{2} (\ln a + 1)  +c + O(a^{-2})\,, \tag{2}$$
depending on the yet undetermined integration constant $c$.

In order to obtain $I(1)$, we a solution for another value of $a$. A natural choice is $a=0$ for which we have to solve the integral
$$ I(0) =  \int_0^\infty \frac{2\ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx\,.$$

Here, I would like to use a different approach and look at the limit $a\to \infty$. In this limit, we have (from (1))
$$ I(a) =\int_0^\infty \frac{2 \ln a}{(1+x^2)^2} + O(a^{-2}) = \frac\pi2 \ln a + O(a^{-2})\,.$$
Comparing this asymptotic expression to the expansion of (2), we find $c= -\pi/2$.

Putting everything together, we obtain
$$I(1) = \frac{\pi}{4} (1 + 2 \ln 2) +c = \frac{\pi}{4}(2 \ln 2 -1)\,.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas) (and gamma/[digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)) functions.

The integral is $-f'(2)$, where $$f(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^a}=\frac12\mathrm{B}\left(\frac12,a-\frac12\right),$$ so that $f'(a)/f(a)=\psi(a-1/2)-\psi(a)$.

Now use $f(2)=\pi/4$, $\psi(2)=1-\gamma$, $\psi(3/2)=2-\gamma-2\log2$.

Answer (score 1):

Given the simpler integral $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx  =\pi \ln2$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1+x^2 \right)}{\left( 1+x^2 \right) ^2}dx\\
=& \
\frac12 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{(1+x^2)\ln (1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}
 +\frac{(1-x^2)\ln (1+x^2)}{( 1+x^2 ) ^2}\ dx\\
 = &\ \frac12 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx  + \frac12\int_0^{\infty}\ln (1+x^2)\ \overset{ibp}d\left( \frac{x}{ 1+x^2 }\right)\\
 = &\ \frac12(\pi\ln2 )- \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{ (1+x^2 )^2}dx
= \frac\pi2\ln2 - \frac\pi4
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Numerically
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\text{Log}\left[1+ x^2\right]}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2} =0.303359$$

$$\int da \  \int_0^\infty  dx  \ \partial_a\ \frac{\log (1+ a^2x^2)}{(1+a^2 \ x^2)^2} = -\frac{\pi }{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Log}[16]}{8 a} $$

For a=1

$$\frac{1}{8} \pi  (-2+\log16)=0.303395$$